# Hostinger Website Builder, embedded Javascript can't access document body

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a Hostinger website builder created website and I'm trying to add titles to the anchor tags by accessing through Javascript using their data attributes.  I inspected the web page in question and got the data attribute values for each of the anchor tags (hyperlinks).  Then I embedded the following code into the bottom of the section containing the anchors:

```
<script>
function imLoaded() {
debugger
    var hyp = document.querySelectorAll('[data-page-id]');
    for (var i=0; i < hyp.length; i++) {
        switch (hyp[i].dataset.pageId) {
            case 'zgkVBI':
                hyp[i].title = "this is title one";
                break;
            case 'zW5Rwe':
                hyp[i].title = "this is title two";
                break;
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", imLoaded);
</script>
```

In the body are the anchor tags:

```
<a href='myserver.com' data-page-id="zgkVBI">This is a test</a>
<a href='myserver.com' data-page-id="zW5Rwe">This is another test</a>
```

1. I've tested the javascript in a text web page outside the website builder and it works
2. The debugger is hit an I can step through the code
3. I created a watch variable using document.body.innerHTML and all I see is the javascript code
4. I use a function and the load event listener to make sure the document body was loaded before running the script.

So, how do I reference the web page's body from the Javascript?.. Where is it?

PS. This won't make sense without using the Hostinger Website Builder (formerly Zyro) as it is specific to that product. There is no Hostinger tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Hostinger Website Builder, however, based on what you described I believe it is because the code is inside an iframe. If document.body.innerHTML only shows the script then that must be it.
Which means, therefore, that you are only looking at the iframe document and not the page document. The scope is wrong. To fix this you can move up to the main scope with this code:

```
window.top.document
```

If that's right, you need to change all document to window.top.document

In devtools you can see what scope your code is in this part shown in the image:
[image]

Comment: Excellent!  That worked.  I had tried similar ways to access the top document but that was the right way!  I found  that I could use code via "Integrations" but that put the code in EVERY page.  So, your suggestion is better.